# Reload configurations without restarting Emacs

Tags: emacs, loading, restart

How do I load the edited `.emacs` file without restarting Emacs?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

M-x eval-buffer

Comment: This works only if you were editing the ".emacs" file itself.

Comment: This does not seem to work when changing the font size.

Answer (score 27):

I usually use M-x load-file.  But be aware that some initialization is only done the first time through.  Things like libraries that set their defaults when loaded, but don't get reloaded the second time through.  Its always a good idea to start up emacs from scratch as a final check that everything works ok.

Answer (score 11):

In the `*scratch*` buffer, type:

```
(load-file user-init-file)
```

Then press `C-x C-e` to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 7):

M-x load-file and then choose the .emacs file should also work

Answer (score 7):

M-x load-file ~/.emacs

eval-buffer when the .emacs file is opened

eval-region when you want apply selected lines

C-x C-e evaluates the preceding expression

Comment: `C-x C-e` evaluates the preceding *expression*, which may span multiple lines.

Answer (score 6):

```
M-x load-file ENTER
~/.emacs
ENTER
```

([source](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/07/how-to-reload-your-emacs-file-while/))

Answer (score 5):

Open the .emacs file, select its contents and hit C-x,C-e

Answer (score 2):

you can use `C-x C-e` which will evaluate an s-expression. Make sure the cursor is at the last parenthesis of the elisp code.

Answer (score 2):

I use and recommend restart-emacs package on melpa