# How can I reload .emacs after changing it?

Tags: emacs

How can I get Emacs to reload all my definitions that I have updated in `.emacs` without restarting Emacs?

Comment: I know emacs is often considered an OS, but...s/reboot/restart/?

Comment: I'm not a developer, so alot of the answers that make sense immediately to developers don't mean that much to me

Comment: @MJB the purpose of Stack Overflow is to be a knowledge repository for even the most basic of questions.  This question fits in perfectly with the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281593/how-can-i-load-changes-to-my-emacs-without-rebooting-emacs

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate, thanks. I didn't see the other one when I posted

Comment: I did not intend to sound so condescending. I realize that even basic questions are ask-able here, but I was serious that a google search was quicker than waiting for an answer.  My apologies.

Comment: No worries MJB. I'm learning to google stuff more and more all the time, but usually I get much more "understandable" (for me at least) answers from stack overflow

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reload configurations without restarting Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167705/reload-configurations-without-restarting-emacs)

Comment: haha now five years later the suggested "Google search first" leads here! nice

Comment: @JimLohse and another 5 years, and most of the first-page search results on "emacs load .emacs" are here or stack exchange.  i sometimes wonder if people realize that for google to deliver good answers, somebody has to write them.

Answer (score 411, accepted):

You can use the command load-file (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `load-file`, and then press <kbd>Return</kbd> twice to accept the default filename, which is the current file being edited).

You can also just move the point to the end of any sexp and press <kbd>C-x</kbd>, <kbd>C-e</kbd> to execute just that sexp. Usually it's not necessary to reload the whole file if you're just changing a line or two.

Comment: Keep in mind that this may not always do exactly what you think it does.  If you have variables whose contents are flopped( ie setting a boolean to it's opposite) then the behavior won't be the same as loading the file.

Comment: Any side-effects in general are likely to break the desired behavior: loading files, etc.

Comment: When I do this, I get the message: load-with-code-conversion: Symbol's value as variable is void: n

Comment: Instead of moving point behind a `defun` or `defvar`, you can also leave it inside the declaration body and type `C-M-x`. Very handy.

Comment: What about `M-x load-file` then `~/.emacs` in place of default.

Answer (score 182):

There is the very convenient

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-buffer`

It immediately evaluates all code in the buffer. It's the quickest method if your *.emacs* file is idempotent.

Comment: Who says that `.emacs` is (or has to be) idempotent?

Comment: @mike : not me.  "Given a, b is true" meant for me, "if a, b is true"   , but I can see what you mean.  I change given to if for more clarity.

Comment: @mike: When would it make sense for  `.emacs` not to be idempotent?

Comment: I would have thought this to be the first suggestion.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is good style but it might happen. For example you could choose not to redefine a function if it is already defined (from the first startup). You might not see a change in its definition when evaluating your init file.

Comment: The useful functions are `eval-buffer` and `eval-defun`. I have these bound to C-c C-k and C-c C-c, respectively (same keys as SLIME). I rarely actually eval the whole buffer, usually only evaling the function or definitions I'm actually working on.

Comment: @GeorgeKettleborough doesn't `C-c C-c` collide with the escapes you use when hosting a shell? All emacs commands starting with `C-x ...` are mapped to `C-c ...`, when using the bash through `term`.

Comment: @Zaz I don't use emacs heavily enough to have run into this use-case, and I would strive to make things idempotent precisely to have this kind of stuff never matter, but I've definitely had situations in life where it was just simpler to code something in a not-idempotent way. For example, in my `zsh` config, for several years I had a piece of code that added a prefix to `PS1` - if that file was sourced on its own, it wasn't idempotent (though it was idempotent if the whole config was sourced). I imagine there exist more than zero situations for `.emacs` where it's easier to skip idempotency.

Answer (score 49):

You can usually just re-evaluate the changed region.  Mark the region of ~/.emacs that you've changed, and then use `M-x eval-region RET`.  This is often safer than re-evaluating the entire file since it's easy to write a .emacs file that doesn't work quite right after being loaded twice.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't considered the idea of a .emacs file that wasn't idempotent. Something to watch out for as I start with ELisp

Comment: I would guess it's rare to find an .emacs file that *is* idempotent, at least in the strong sense of two executions resulting in exactly the same state as one execution.  At the very least, it's quite common to append to various lists, often in ways that won't suppress duplicate entries when executed a second time.

Comment: One other thought: using the approach I suggest above, it's possible that the emacs state you've got isn't what your .emacs actually does.  Ie, since you haven't executed the entire .emacs file from a clean slate, you don't *actually* know it does what you want.

Comment: That being said, wouldn't it be possible to write .emacs in an idempotent way? Global state is icky.

Answer (score 47):

If you've got your .emacs file open in the currently active buffer:

```
M-x eval-buffer
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of here is that doing this *may* not leave you in a state identical to a restart approach. (Contrived example: if you had a "toggle" affect in your .emacs).

Answer (score 34):

#### Solution

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(load user-init-file)`

---

#### Notes

- you type it in `Eval:` prompt (including the parentheses)
- [`user-init-file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Init-File.html) is a variable holding the  `~/.emacs` value (pointing to the configuration file path) by default
- [`(load)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Loading-Files.html) is shorter, older, and non-interactive version of [`(load-file)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html); it is not an Emacs command (to be typed in <kbd>M-x</kbd>), but a mere [Elisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp) function

---

#### Conclusion

`M-:` > `M-x`

Comment: is M-: > Ctrl Alt x? based on your logic I imagine M-: < C-M-x when only one line in the init file is changed? Maybe it's just ==

Answer (score 30):

```
M-x load-file
~/.emacs
```

Comment: Doing this I learned that on my Windows 7 installation, the .emacs.d folder was located in the %appdata% folder instead of the users home folder.

Answer (score 16):

Others already answered your question as stated, but I find that I usually want to execute the lines that I just wrote.

For that, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> in the [Elisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp) part works just fine.

Comment: See also `eval-lastsexp`, at `C-x C-e`

Comment: With `C-M-x`, you don't have to be "at the end of the lisp" -- are you thinking of `C-x C-e` perhaps? The nice thing about `C-M-x` is that you can invoke it even when point is in the middle of a function/variable declaration.

Comment: I probably got into the habit of going to end of lisp at the time I only used C-x C-e. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 13):

The following should do it...

```
M-x load-file
```

Answer (score 12):

I suggest that you don't do this, initially.  Instead, start a new Emacs session and test whatever changes you made to see if they work correctly.  The reason to do it this way is to avoid leaving you in a state where you have an inoperable *.emacs* file, which fails to load or fails to load cleanly.  If you do all of your editing in the original session, and all of your testing in a new session, you'll always have something reliable to comment out offending code.

When you are finally happy with your changes, then go ahead and use one of the other answers to reload.  My personal preference is to `eval` just the section you've added/changed, and to do that just highlight the region of added/changed code and call `M-x eval-region`.  Doing that minimizes the code that's evaluated, minimizing any unintentional side-effects, as [luapyad points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580650/how-can-i-reload-emacs-after-changing-it#comment2247241_2281628).

Answer (score 10):

Keyboard shortcut:

```
(defun reload-init-file ()
  (interactive)
  (load-file user-init-file))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-l") 'reload-init-file)    ; Reload .emacs file
```

Answer (score 8):

```
C-x C-e ;; current line
M-x eval-region ;; region
M-x eval-buffer ;; whole buffer
M-x load-file ~/.emacs.d/init.el
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11913712/edit), not here in comments (****************** ***without*** ****************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 5):

Define it in your init file and call by **M-x reload-user-init-file**

```
(defun reload-user-init-file()
  (interactive)
  (load-file user-init-file))
```

Comment: This is actually my preferred answer: take something that exists, and make it accessible by M-x (rather than M-: and extra typing). M-x is indeed the normal way to access useful commands that are not common enough to deserve their own keybinding.

Comment: Best answer, as it also works if your config lives in `~/.config/emacs/` instead of `~/.emacs.d/`

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently on [Ubuntu 15.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_15.04_.28Vivid_Vervet.29) (Vivid Vervet); I like to define a key for this.

[M-insert] translates to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd> on my keyboard.

Put this in your *.emacs* file:

```
(global-set-key [M-insert] '(lambda() (interactive) (load-file "~/.emacs")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides commands like **M-x eval-buffer** or **M-x load-file**, you can restart a fresh Emacs instance from the command line:

```
emacs -q --load "init.el"
```

Usage example: *[Company backends in GNU Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959535/company-backends-in-gnu-emacs/44965615#44965615)*

Comment: The question asks how to do this without restarting Emacs. Launching a new copy, while [technically](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo) answering the question, doesn't seem to fit the spirit of the question. 

Answer (score 2):

Although `M-x eval-buffer` will work, you may run into problems with toggles and other similar things. A better approach might be to "mark" or highlight what’s new in your *.emacs* file (or even scratch buffer if you're just messing around) and then `M-x eval-region`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and easy way to quick test your config. You can also use `C-x C-e` at the end of specific lisp to execute certain function individually.

> C-x C-e runs the command eval-last-sexp (found in global-map), which
>   is an interactive compiled Lisp function.
>
> It is bound to C-x C-e.
>
> (eval-last-sexp EVAL-LAST-SEXP-ARG-INTERNAL)
>
> Evaluate sexp before point; print value in the echo area.
>   Interactively, with prefix argument, print output into current buffer.
>
> Normally, this function truncates long output according to the value
>   of the variables ‘eval-expression-print-length’ and
>   ‘eval-expression-print-level’.  With a prefix argument of zero,
>   however, there is no such truncation.  Such a prefix argument also
>   causes integers to be printed in several additional formats (octal,
>   hexadecimal, and character).
>
> If ‘eval-expression-debug-on-error’ is non-nil, which is the default,
>   this command arranges for all errors to enter the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a key binding for Emacs like this:

```
;; Reload Emacs configuration
(defun reload-init-file ()
  (interactive)
  (load-file "~/.emacs"))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") 'reload-init-file)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you happen to have a shell opened inside Emacs, you can also do:

```
. ~/.emacs
```

It may save a few key strokes.