# Reset definitions and reload .emacs without closing, or restart Emacs and re-open buffers

Tags: emacs

As far as I understand, the following sequence of commands

```
M-x load-file ENTER
~/.emacs
ENTER
```

would re-load my `.emacs` file. However, from what I have read on other forums, they are not guaranteed to give me a totally revised configuration, i.e. they would force Emacs to parse the new configuration file and reload modified variable and function definitions, but they would not remove previously loaded definitions.

With this, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to clear ups Emacs's definitions in memory and re-load `.emacs` without having to fully restart Emacs?
2. If the above is not possible, is there a way to restart Emacs (so that I parses my `.emacs` file from scratch) asking it to re-open all buffers that I have open?

Comment: +1 to counter the (strange) downvote... what's wrong with this question?

Comment: Why are you trying to reload the whole file?  Parts of the file that you know have changed can be re run with eval-region

Comment: Let's say you have `(setq config-var t)` for some variable whose default value is `nil`. If you delete this line from the file you can't reproduce the default behavior by reloading just that part of the file (which is now empty), or even the whole file. You have to keep track of each change you make and undo it somehow, which is fraught with peril and may not even be possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reload .emacs for all active buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211615/reload-emacs-for-all-active-buffers)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Undoing everything that might have been done in your `.emacs` is impossible.

You can save and restore an emacs session with `desktop`. Quit with `M-x desktop-save RET C-x C-c` and then restore with `emacs -f desktop-read`.

See `(info "(emacs) Saving Emacs Sessions")` for more information. (You can also `customize` `desktop-save-mode` so that this behavior is the default.)

Comment: See also http://porkmail.org/elisp/recover-buffers/ which allows you to revisit all the buffers you had open when Emacs quit or crashed.  Disclosure: I wrote that.

Answer (score 7):

This question is a duplicate, but as it has an accepted answer I'll repeat my comments about the Desktop library which is that it stores a certain amount of state (modes and local variables) with each buffer that it saves, and it then *restores that same state* when it reloads those files.

In your case, of course, this is exactly what you *don't* want to happen.

See [Reload .emacs for all active buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211615/reload-emacs-for-all-active-buffers/7212097#7212097) for a simple way to revert (reload) all the buffers.

Combining the two approaches would let you restart Emacs, with Desktop restoring the files, at which point you could revert all the files.